# Pass HTML to mat dialog - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material-6

I am trying to pass HTML to mat dialog but it shows `[object HTMLTableElement]` in the dialog instead of Table HTML.

Steps I have Tried:

1. Made an Element Ref in template as below:

   ```
   <table hidden #contentTable><th></th><tr></tr></table>
   ```
2. Accessed ViewChild in component as

   ```
   @ViewChild('contentTable', { read: ElementRef }) contentTable: ElementRef<any>;
   ```
3. Passed this as Data in DialogComponent as

   ```
   const tableData = this.contentTable.nativeElement;
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(GeneralDialogComponent, {
       panelClass: 'customDialog',
        data: {
           title: `${data.count}`,
           content: tableData
        }
   });
   ```
4. In DialogComponent, accessed data content as below:

   ```
   // method in component
   getHtml(html) {
      return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
   }
   ```
5. Then in HTML accessed like this:

   ```
   <div [innerHTML]="getHtml(data?.content)"></div>
   ```

but it does not print Table instead it prints `[object HTMLTableElement]`.

Screenshot as below:

[image]

Any leads please?

Comment: Does your `tableData` contain any `<br>` tags??

Comment: No... It is ElementRef

Answer (score 2):

you should pass the innerHtml of elementRef not itself:

```
<div [innerHTML]="getHtml(data?.content.innerHTML)"></div>
```

Comment: It will not print table then.. as i need outerHTML but that is not available in ElementRef

Comment: i don't get error because of ElementRef and outerHTML works but it's not as expected too.

Comment: it returns empty HTML.. any more suggestions please..shall i try to user TemplteRef?

Comment: I am doing it in MAT Dialog... does that make difference?

Comment: no difference [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-style-string-sanitizer-ar39si)

Comment: check [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-4vms1u) using mat dialog.